# Bootstrap and Bootstrapvalidator: How to show a success alert after successful validation?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation, bootstrapvalidator

I am playing a little bit with bootstrap and bootstrapvalidator to validate my forms. Everything works fine, but now I want to make an alert show up, that the message was send successfully (or redirect to a success.html page). Here is the html code as an example:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="order">
  <input type="text" name="name"/><br>
  <input type="text" name="email"/><br>
  <textarea name="comment"></textarea><br>
  <button type="submit" name="send" id="send">Send</button>
  <div class="alert alert-success" id="asked">
  <strong>Success!</strong> Indicates a successful or positive action.
</div>
</form>
```

Here is a snippet of the validation jquery code:

**JQUERY:**

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var validator = $('#order').bootstrapValidator({
            fields: {
                email : {
                    message : "Please insert Email", 
                    validators : {
                        notEmpty : {
                            message : "Insert a valid email address"
                        },
                        stringLength : {
                            min : 6,
                            max: 35,
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    });
});
```

What also worked for me is to hide the alert and show after the button was clicked:

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#asked").hide();
});

$('#send').click(function() {
$.post('php/text.php', $('form#order').serialize());
$("#asked").show();
});
```

Now I want to make the alert show up, if everything in the validation is green. Even the $.post method worked only after the validation is successful. How can I achieve the same with the alert message? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should use "**onSuccess function**".

You can see here:
[Bootstrap Validator - Alert on success validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27251680/bootstrap-validator-alert-on-success-validation)

Comment: Could you specify more!